# Is there a way to enable HTTPS on Elastic Beanstalk without a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is my first time using AWS or any other such platform. I require an https on my website because I use stripe. I have already got an SSL certificate using AWS certificate manager. But the only way to use that is if you have a load balancer on your instance. I do not want to pay for a load balancer because it is too small of a project to do so.

Any other ways to enable HTTPS without a Load Balancer?

Comment: ACM certificates can only be used with AWS load balancers and Amazon CloudFront distributions. Note that ALB pricing is something like $15-20 per month for a very small system. The cert will also be auto-renewed which saves you time, effort, and the risk of downtime.

Comment: @dhairyakhara aws is saying that ACM is free of cost but you can only use ACM with  AWS load balancers also, load balancers are costing around $15-$20 which means we've to pay a minimum of $15 to enable SSL certificate in it

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be through CloudFront (CF):

- [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudfront.html)

For that you would create a CF distribution and setup your SSL certificate and a **custom domain** (required), and setup EB environment as a custom origin.

The **alternative** would be to configure nginx on your EB instance to use SSL. For that you would have too check out some tutorials or docs on how to use nginx to serve https requests. Some example:

- [How to enable SSL on NGINX](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-ssl-on-nginx/)

But this will not work with ACM certificates from what I recall. This is one limitation of such an approach.

Comment: If the OP is trying to avoid the (relatively low) cost of ALB, I suspect that CloudFront might also prove to be undesirable.  The solution is probably to *not* use ACM, get certs elsewhere as cheaply as possible, and install them directly on EC2 (or EB) instances.

Comment: @jarmod Hi. Yes, its possible. Thus I also included the alternative solution of configuring  nginx for SSL on the EB instance.

Comment: @Marcin. I am trying the first option. But it seems I keep getting redirected to beanstalk url.

Comment: It would be nice to explain how to setup an EBS with cloudfront.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by jarmod, you can only use ACM certificates with ALB or Cloudfront which both are not free. As far as I know, there is no completely free AWS service that accomplishes this. You can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for free auto-renewable certificates to install on your webserver.

Answer (score -1):

We can use eb-extensions to deploy the SSL certificate from S3 and add it as part of the environment variable -> For detailed reference please refer to this [doc](https://askyblue.com/aws-ebs-nginx/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the link is down.